# C# Linq query returning more than one match

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get one boat item from the `Boat` table only if that boat is not in the `RentBoat` table and has a value on the `IsOnRent` column set to true.

This is my code so far:

```
db.Boats.SingleOrDefault(x => !db.RentBoats.Any(s => s.BoatID == x.BoatID && s.IsOnRent == true));
```

The error I am getting is:

> The sequence contains several elements

Where is my code wrong? Any help would be great.

Essentially I want what this query does but I want it to return the matched item from an Id or return null.(a singel item not a list)

```
db.Boats.Where(boat => !db.RentBoats.Any(x => x.BoatID == boat.BoatID && x.IsOnRent == true)).ToList();

public class Boat
{
    [Key]
    public int BoatID { get; set; }

    public string BoatName { get; set; }
}

public class RentBoat
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int RentBoatID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Boat")]
    public int BoatID { get; set; }

    public string BoatName { get; set; }
    public bool IsOnRent { get; set; }

    public virtual  Boat Boat { get; set; }
}
```

> EDIT

This is how I solved it in the end:

```
    using (var db = new BoatContext())
            {
                List<RentBoat> IsBoatRented = db.RentBoats.Where(x => x.BoatID == boatId && x.IsOnRent == true).ToList();
                if (IsBoatRented.Count() == 0)
                {
                    returnedBoat = db.Boats.FirstOrDefault(x => x.BoatID == boatId);
                }                  

            }
```

I know it isn't as efficient or good looking as one single query. But couldn't make this with one query. If somebody can rewrite these queries to one query. Fell free to help. I would appreciate it.

Comment: @GiladGreen - it doesnt seems like duplicate

Comment: Doesn't `Boats` have a navigational property to `RentBoats`?

Comment: can you please paste you Boats class ...may be that helps

Comment: hwo may recoreds retuned by where ???

Comment: updated question with classes

Comment: after lookint at your class structure , this query `!db.RentBoats.Any(s => s.BoatID == x.BoatID && s.IsOnRent == true)` will return you mutiple recrods , it will return you all the boats where `IsOnRent=false`..i think you should double check your table records and improve you query accordingly...

Comment: as I suggested you ..you need `where` condition with distinct not `SingleOrDegault`.....

Comment: updated my answer hopet that might help you

Answer (score 2):

By using `SingleOrDefault` you're saying that there should ever only be one record matching the condition. The error says there are multiple rows in the database which match what you're asking for.

If you want one result but don't really care if there is only one successful match use `FirstOrDefault` instead. It will return one row if there is one or more records matching the predicate or `null` if there is none.

Answer (score 2):

you should try like this , get all non rented boats (your query may give you boat with same id mutiple times) and to avoid that appply group by

```
var allNotRendedBoats= from b in db.Boats
                          .Where(boat => !db.RentBoats
                          .Any(x => x.BoatID == boat.BoatID && x.IsOnRent == true))
                 group b by b.BoatID into g
select g.First();
```

if its not going to return you same boat multiple times than just put where conditon instead of `SingleOrDefault` give you output

---

seemd like issue with `!` condition

```
db.Boats.SingleOrDefault(x => 
    !db.RentBoats.Any(s => s.BoatID == x.BoatID && s.IsOnRent == true));
```

it should be

```
db.Boats.SingleOrDefault(x => 
     db.RentBoats.Any(s => s.BoatID == x.BoatID && s.IsOnRent == true));
```

if you do `!` then you are requested more then one element

So if i go through your code , then seems like you are request all element which are not maching this condition `!db.RentBoats.Any(s => s.BoatID == x.BoatID && s.IsOnRent == true))`

`SingleOrDefault` is useful when you are expecting only one element,

if you want to get first element then I suggest make use of `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: I totally missed that. Good catch! But even with that fix I think it's safe to assume there are more than one boat available for rental and `SingleOrDefault` should really be `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - thanks , i updated same thing in my answer ... :) hope it helps him

Comment: In the RentBoat table there will be alot of boats with the same Id. I want to cross match when I get the boats from table Boats that I dont get Boats that are rented out already.

Comment: @AllramEst -if you want to figure out what is the issue then i suggest you apply where condtion and check how many element is returned by condition ...

Comment: @AllramEst - can you please try and let me know ...add wehere condtion and check the lenght and print element retunred ...